# How to make a popup that overlaps other elements?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Suppose I've got a bunch of rows that contain a few elements. When user hover over some element, a popup info should show up beneath the element. Besides, that popup isn't supposed to make other elements move, it has to overlap the other elements but not shift them.

How can this be achieved?

```css
.ball:hover {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.ball:hover .info {
  display: block;
}

.info {
  z-index: 1;
  display: none;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  margin-top: 1.1em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class='row'>
  <div class='ball col-xs-4'>
    <img src='http://www.iconsearch.ru/uploads/icons/developerkit/128x128/ballblue.png'>
    <div class='info'>This popup info should overlap the bottom element but not shift it.</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class='ball col-xs-4'>
    <img src='http://www.iconsearch.ru/uploads/icons/developerkit/128x128/ballblue.png'>
    <div class='info'>This popup info should overlap the bottom element but not shift it.</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class='ball col-xs-4'>
    <img src='http://www.iconsearch.ru/uploads/icons/developerkit/128x128/ballblue.png'>
    <div class='info'>This popup info should overlap the bottom element but not shift it.</div>
  </div>
  
   <div class='ball col-xs-4'>
    <img src='http://www.iconsearch.ru/uploads/icons/developerkit/128x128/ballblue.png'>
  </div>
  
  <div class='ball col-xs-4'>
    <img src='http://www.iconsearch.ru/uploads/icons/developerkit/128x128/ballblue.png'>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try adding `max-height: 128px;` (ball image height) to `.ball`. Is that what you've meant?

Comment: Make sure to use position properties `absolute` or `fixed` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this? Give your ball a 1px solid transparent border and the .info a position of absolute.

```css
.ball{
  border:1px solid transparent;
}
.ball:hover {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.ball:hover .info {
  display: block;
}

.info {
  z-index: 1;
  display: none;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  margin-top:1px;
  padding-top: 1.1em;
  position:absolute;
  background-color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class='row'>
  <div class='ball col-xs-4'>
    <img src='http://www.iconsearch.ru/uploads/icons/developerkit/128x128/ballblue.png'>
    <div class='info'>This popup info should overlap the bottom element but not shift it.</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class='ball col-xs-4'>
    <img src='http://www.iconsearch.ru/uploads/icons/developerkit/128x128/ballblue.png'>
    <div class='info'>This popup info should overlap the bottom element but not shift it.</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class='ball col-xs-4'>
    <img src='http://www.iconsearch.ru/uploads/icons/developerkit/128x128/ballblue.png'>
    <div class='info'>This popup info should overlap the bottom element but not shift it.</div>
  </div>
  
   <div class='ball col-xs-4'>
    <img src='http://www.iconsearch.ru/uploads/icons/developerkit/128x128/ballblue.png'>
  </div>
  
  <div class='ball col-xs-4'>
    <img src='http://www.iconsearch.ru/uploads/icons/developerkit/128x128/ballblue.png'>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, but other than that it should have a white background so that a part of  the bottom ball is not visible.

Comment: I edited it, and added a background-color of white. I also changed your margin to a padding, then added a margin-top of 1px to account for the red border.

Answer (score 0):

html

```
<div class='row'>
  <div class='ball col-xs-4'>
    <img src='http://www.iconsearch.ru/uploads/icons/developerkit/128x128/ballblue.png'>
    <div class='info'>This popup info should overlap the bottom element but not shift it.</div>
  </div>

  <div class='ball col-xs-4'>
    <img src='http://www.iconsearch.ru/uploads/icons/developerkit/128x128/ballblue.png'>
    <div class='info'>This popup info should overlap the bottom element but not shift it.</div>
  </div>

  <div class='ball col-xs-4'>
    <img src='http://www.iconsearch.ru/uploads/icons/developerkit/128x128/ballblue.png'>
    <div class='info'>This popup info should overlap the bottom element but not shift it.</div>
  </div>

   <div class='ball col-xs-4'>
    <img src='http://www.iconsearch.ru/uploads/icons/developerkit/128x128/ballblue.png'>
  </div>

  <div class='ball col-xs-4'>
    <img src='http://www.iconsearch.ru/uploads/icons/developerkit/128x128/ballblue.png'>
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.ball:hover {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.ball:hover .info {
  display: block;
}
.ball
{
  position: relative;
  border:1px solid transparent;
}
.info {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  display: none;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  margin-top: 1.1em;
  bottom:0;
  background-color: #fff;

}
```

here is link for reference
 [codepen link](https://codepen.io/chandrashekhar/pen/RgRqOP?editors=1100)